# Can Theano / Pytorch / Tensorflow compute the following gradient automatically?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to run a recurrent neural network where the state update function for each neuron is the following

```
z = g*y
```

given that

```
g = (x<x_max & x>x_max-e) | (x>-x_max & x<-x_max+e)
```

Note that all the variables here are just scalars.

The variable x is defined in a way that it will always  update continually so that g will always be a pulse as shown in the [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BDYc.png). That is, g won't be 1 for a single update but it will be 1 for several consecutive updates.

Can any of these packages implement an automatic gradient computation given this transfer function?

Answer (score 0):

The gradient can't be computed.

`g` as you have shown is a binary variable. So it's gradient can't be computed. Even the wave-form you have plotted has gradient 0 everywhere except at two points (where its infinite, function is discontinuous)